# product thumbnail images slider on magento product detail page

Tags: magento

How can we add product thumbnail images slider  on magento product detail page and when user clicks on thumbnail that image is shown in place of large image

Comment: check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35824/20064

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?